# print in contract not showing output in eosjs docker

Tags: smart-contract, development

i want to print some logs in eosjs docker version. But somehow it is not showing anything. 
I have set: `# print contract's output to console (eosio::chain_plugin)
contracts-console = true` in the config.ini which is in eosjs docker folder. I restarted eos but it is not showing any log.

I included `#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>` and do the printing like that: `print("\n>>> user >>>", user, " - name: ", name{ user });`

Comment: same problem here even though i included --contracts-console option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting the `nodeos` process with the `--contracts-console` option in the command line to force it to enable it in case it wasn't using that specific config file or something like that.

Besides that, try being more specific with the print function by prefixing it with the eosio namespace, like `eosio::print`, and also try printing just a literal string before printing more complex things, like `eosio::print("HELLOOOOOO")`.

Answer (score -1):

use library -> eosiolib/print.hpp
then try using printf instead of print